# Outcome Dependant Columns

Tags: list, custom-list, column

I'm creating a list to track pieces of work that are currently ongoing and under review - each item can sit in 1 of 4 stages which are

```
Stage 1
Stage 2
Stage 3
Closed
```

If the user selects stage 2 from the drop down I want some additional columns to appear that will need to be populated, any ideas?

I'm relatively new to doing this, so if you could keep your answers basic so I can understand it will be much appreciated!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to show/hide fields on sharepoint list forms. Using jQuery, you can control the visibility of fields.

For example refer [this link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21730.sharepoint-2010-conditionally-hide-fields-on-standard-list-forms-using-jquery.aspx).

Comment: Brilliant I'll take a look - I'm not sure if it will impact on the answer given but I'm using 2003 will the jQuery still work in that as taking a brief look at the link it references 2010?

Comment: sorry not 2003 it's version 3.0!

Comment: I believe jquery should work with WSS 3.0 or else you can use javascript http://pawansatope.blogspot.in/2011/10/javascript-and-sharepoint-list-form.html